# Storing pointer to heap objects in an STL container for later deallocation

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, cuda

How can one store an arbitrary number of dynamically created instances (of different types) in an STL container so that the memory can be freed later only having the container?

It should work like this:

```
std::vector< void * > vec;
vec.push_back( new int(10) );
vec.push_back( new float(1.) );
```

Now, if `vec` goes out of scope the pointers to the instances are destructed, but the memory for `int` and `float` are not freed. And obviously I can't do:

```
for( auto i : vec )
  delete *i;
```

because `void*` is not a pointer-to-object type.

You could object and argue that this isn't a good idea because one can not access the elements of the vector. That is right, and I don't access them myself. The NVIDIA driver will access them as it just needs addresses (`void*` is fine) for it parameters to a kernel call.

I guess the problem here is that it can be different types that are stored. Wondering if a `union` can do the trick in case one wants to pass this as arguments to a cuda kernel.

The kernel takes parameters of different types and are collected by traversing an expression tree (expression templates) where you don't know the type beforehand. So upon visiting the leaf you store the parameter. it can only be void*, and built-in types int, float, etc.

The vector can be deleted right after the kernel launch (the launch is async but the driver copies the parameters first then continues host thread). 2nd question: Each argument is passed a void* to the driver. Regardless if its an int, float or even void*. So I guess one can allocate more memory than needed. I think the union thingy might be worth looking at.

Comment: Why would you need such an insane design? Just use `vector<float>` and `vector<int>`. What use would a `void *` be if you don't know the type of the object it's pointing to?

Comment: Is there a limited number of types that can be in there?

Comment: The kernel takes parameters of different types and are collected by traversing an expression tree (expression templates) where you don't know the type beforehand. So upon visiting the leaf you store the parameter. Might be an `int`, `float`, etc

Comment: @Caribou Yeah, it can only be `void*`, and built-in types `int`, `float`, etc.

Comment: well could you malloc it, and then free it then in place new rather than straight new and delete?

Comment: @Caribou that might be possible but is not very C++-ish. Doubt that it would be a great solution

Comment: @Frank - Yes you are right :) but it is a solution and if you are just interested in deleting memory after then it will be the simplest probably (and quickest I suspect)

Comment: I was trying to work out whether an allocator could be used - such as boost::fast_pool_allocator - do you know when the vector can be deleted? and could you allocate a fixed size of memory even if the nvidia process was only going to use part of the memory passed to it?

Comment: The vector can be deleted right after the kernel launch (the launch is async but the driver copies the parameters first then continues host thread). 2nd question: Each argument is passed a `void*` to the driver. Regardless if its an `int`, `float` or even `void*`. So I guess one can allocate more memory than needed. Before you dive too much into a pool allocator, I think the `union` thingy might be worth looking at.

Comment: @Frank I wansn't neccessarily going to dive :)

Comment: If driver copies the arguments, why do you need to allocate them on the heap then? Just declare them all on the local scope and push the pointers to the vector

Comment: Because when launching the kernel I am no longer in scope of the block where the arguments were passed to. Need to store them somewhere

Comment: @Frank, please post a real code then, you may be solving an unexisting problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can use one vector of each type you want to support.

But while that's a great improvement on the idea of a vector of `void*`, it still quite smelly.

This does sound like an **XY-problem**: you have a problem X, you envision a solution Y, but Y obviously doesn't work without some kind of ingenious adaption, so ask about Y. When instead, should be asking about the real problem X. Which is?

Comment: Can't use one vector for each type. Please see comment on question.

Comment: Traversing the parse tree is done at compile time. At library development time the type to store into the vector is not known. This is library (active library, in the sense of Todd Veldhuizen). It depends on the user code (the code that uses the library) what type is to be stored.

Comment: Ok, I try to ask about the real problem. I have a sequence of values of different types and I would need their addresses as an array of `void*` in exactly the order of the sequence. Good thing is that the types can only be void pointers or built-in types.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, FWIW

I would recomend using an in-place new combined with `malloc`. what this would do is allow you store the pointers created as `void*` in your vector. Then when the vector is finished with it can simply be iterated over and `free()` called.

I.E.

```
void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
int* myNiceInt = new (ptr) int(myNiceValue);
vec.push_back(ptr);

//at some point later iterate over vec
free( *iter );
```

I believe that this will be the simplest solution to the problem in this case but do accept that this is a "C" like answer.

Just sayin' ;)

Comment: While we are at it, we could allocate pairs of deallocator functions and data, then take a pointer to second in the vector as void.  When you want to free, undo the offset and get the pair back.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

"NVIDIA driver" sounds like a C interface anyway, so `malloc` is not a crazy suggestion.

Another alternative, as you suggest, is to use a union...  But you will also need to store "tags" in a parallel vector to record the actual type of the element, so that you can cast to the appropriate type on deletion.

In short, you must cast `void *` to an appropriate type before you can `delete` it.  The "C++ way" would be to have a base class with a virtual destructor; you can call `delete` on that when it points to an instance of any sub-class.  But if the library you are using has already determined the types, then that is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the types you can create an abstract base class for them. Give that class a virtual destructor. Then you can have your `std::vector<Object*>` and iterate over it to delete anything which inherits from Object.

You probably need to have a second `std::vector<void*>` with pointers to the actual values, since the `Object*` probably hits the vtable first. A second virtual function like `virtual void* ptr() { return &value; }` would be useful here. And if it needs the size of the object you can add that too.

You could use the template pattern like this:

```
template<typename T>
class ObjVal : public Object {
    public:
    T val;
    virtual void* ptr() { return &this->val; }
    virtual size_t size() { return sizeof(this->val); }
};
```

Then you only have to type it once.

This is not particularly memory efficient because every Object picks up at least one extra pointer for the vtable.

However, `new int(3)` is not very memory efficient either because your allocator probably uses more than 4 bytes for it. Adding that vtable pointer may be essentially free.

Answer (score -1):

Use more than 1 vector.  Keep the `vector<void*>` around to talk to the API (which I'm guessing requires a contiguous block of void*s of non-uniform types?), but also have a `vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` and `vector<std::unique_ptr<float>>` which owns the data.  When you create a `new` int, push a `unique_ptr` that owns the memory into your `vector` of `int`s, and then stick it on the API-compatible `vector` as a `void*`.  Bundle the three `vector`s into one `struct` so that their lifetimes are tied together if possible (and it probably is).

You can also do this with a single vector that stores the ownership of the variables.  A `vector` of roll-your-own RAII pseudo-`unique_ptr`, or `shared_ptr` with custom destroyers, or a `vector` of `std::function<void()>` that your "Bundle"ing struct's destroyer invokes, or what have you.  But I wouldn't recommend these options.